# Is it possible to map custom contact fields to opportunity fields?

Tags: opportunity, contact, field-mapping

Is it possible to map custom fields at the contact object to the opportunity object if the opportunity is created *after* conversion?

For example: if I have a custom lead field called "Favorite Fruit" and it maps to the contact for conversion (there's also a dupe field to map to the opportunity at conversion), but rather than create the opportunity during the conversion process, it's created at a later point from the contact record, can I set the mapping for that situation?

Or is this not possible without a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a lead is converted to Contact, Opportunity, updates to Contact fields are not synced to Opportunity. You will have to handle that task yourself.

Comment: This is not actually the answer to what he was asking. We are creating Opportunities from Contacts as well, and need to have several custom fields from the originating contact's record to flow to the Opportunity created via the "New" button on the Contact's record. Can anyone assist?